# disable foreign key constraint in MSAccess

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, foreign-keys

During data transfer i want to disable/enable

- All foreign keys on table
- All foreign keys on all tables

via query in **MSAccess**. 
I will call query it from C# Module. There will be bulk insertion.

Comment: Via query or during a query, e.g. during insert/update like described here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/disable-a-constraint-adp-HP003088260.aspx

Comment: @D.R. i have updated question, i will be calling disable/enable foreign key/checks etc query via C# project. so want to perform things in link via query not GUI

Comment: I don't think this is possible in Access (that link states it is for ADP files only), and especially not with a query. It *may* be possible through VBA, in which you could temporarily store the relationships, then delete them, do your bulk insert, and re-add them after (code example for accessing/deleting relationships: http://allenbrowne.com/DelRel.html), but it wouldn't handle the fact that some data you added may violate the relationships so be VERY careful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could delete your relationship from `MSysRelationships` do your stuff, make sure it is all valid then recreate the record in `MSysRelationships`.

This seems difficult though. You're knowingly putting bad data into a table with constraints. Why not put your data into a temp table with the same design as your table with the constraints then use an insert query to move the records in to the canonical table according to the rules you've established in the relationships. That way you don't ever drop relationships and risk ruining your table with bad data.

Comment: Thanks.Although i did not like the solution, but i did not find any other and i was trying to skip this.